# Simple web application filter doesn't filter request

Tags: spring-mvc, servlet-filters

Starting my way with STS and created a new basic "Hello World" Spring MVC project.
I wanted to add a filter to my app so I created a filter (HelloWorldFilter.java) with the following doFilter method:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Entering Filter");
        request.setAttribute("hello", "Hello World from HelloWorldFilter!");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        System.out.println("Exiting HelloWorldFilter");
    }
```

According to what I read it (my filter) should also be defined in the application context as a spring bean (Spring delegates it to my filter - from [this manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) )

So in my application context I have:

```
<bean id="helloWorldFilter" class="com.yl.mvc.filters.HelloWorldFilter"> </bean>
```

My web.xml contains the following:

```
<filter>
    <display-name>HelloWorldFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>HelloWorldFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HelloWorldFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In my .jsp file I added:

```
<P><%=request.getAttribute("hello")%></P>
```

But all I see in my web-page is null (I expected Hello World from HelloWorldFilter!).
The filter doesn't even get invoked..

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance,
Yogi

Comment: To avoid the obvious, did you rebuild/redeploy/restart the webapp? Filters are namely initialized only once on webapp's startup. So you can't add one to an already running webapp by just editing `web.xml`.

Comment: Indeed :) I also did some reading and saw that I should update my web.xml. I will edit the question in a sec. Thanks

Comment: Ok go it solved. There was a name mismatch.In my application context I had:
    <bean id="helloWorldFilter"...

and in my web.xml:
    <filter-name>HelloWorldFilter</filter-name>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok go it solved.

The filter (which is a spring bean) must have the same name in the bean definition (in the application context) as that in the filter-name element (in the web.xml).

In my case I had in my application context:

```
<bean id="helloWorldFilter"...
```

and in my web.xml:

```
<filter-name>HelloWorldFilter</filter-name>
```

So once it is with a capital H and once a small h - which caused the issue.
To resolve it I simply changed the bean id in my application context to HelloWorldFilter.